# How can i use css media queries in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

**How can i use css media queries in the below jquery?**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.lws_woorewards_sponsorship_submit').click(function() {
    $('.lar-history-grid-title').css('margin-top','-20px');
  });
});
```

****Actually I want to give a margin to .lar-history-grid-title when clicking on that button for mobile only. Max width 768px;****

Answer (score 0):

Check with screen.width or using innerWidth.

```
  if(screen.width <= 768) {
     //Your code
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Am trying that now :)